# How to return a date or an error? c# .Net

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I am trying to return a date in the format "dd / MM / yyyy" from an entered date.
In case the entered date has the following format: "dd-mm-yyyy", I would like to return an error: "The entered date format is not valid."
I share my code:

```
public class DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));

        return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

I tried to do the following, but it is not correct because I have to return a DateTime variable:

```
public class DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));

        try
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = "Date format error";
            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me! Thanks

Comment: The normal way to "return an error" in C# is to just throw an exception. Is there a particular reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: Yes, I imagined it. I wanted to simply return an error that is: "The entered date format is not correct" @RB.

Comment: @GianfrancoGrigera You either need to throw an exception, as RB said, or use the "either" monad pattern. An exception would be cleaner.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!
One more query. How do I return the exception? Because since I'm doing it, it doesn't work for me. @RichardDeeming

Comment: @GianfrancoGrigera You don't *return* an exception; you *throw* an exception. [Exceptions and Exception Handling | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/)

Comment: @GianfrancoGrigera You don't return an exception, you let it go and catch later in the call tree. In your case, you can remove the Try-Catch clause from your Read method, and handle the error in the caller. 
If you really want to return an object with some error state, you can always encapsulate your DateTime in a CustomDateTime object with a bool IsValid and a string OnErrorMessage property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you are implementing `JsonConverter<T>`, which means the implementation should comply to the expected behaviour of the class, which is throwing `JsonException` when input value cannot be converted.

```
public class DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(reader.GetString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result) 
        {
           return result;
        }
        else throw new JsonException();
    }
}
```

I use `TryParseExact` so there's no need to catch exception.

Comment: Perfect! That helped me a lot! Thanks a lot!